# Convert one liner private key to multi-line (original)

Tags: sed

I have to convert RSA private key to one-line to store in the password manager (Passwordstate). I used `tr -d '\n' < id_rsa` to convert to single line and `cat id_rsa.line | sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&\n/" -e "s/\S\{64\}/&\n/g"` to convert back to original multi-line.

Conversion back to multi-line worked on Ubuntu, but not on Mac. Why this doesn't work on Macbook

Comment: Good that you have shown us sample commands, could you please show sample(TEST off course) of  your input and expected output too in your post and let us know then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
LF=$'\\\x0A'
cat id_rsa.line | sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&${LF}/" -e "s/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/${LF}&${LF}/" | sed -e "s/[^[:blank:]]\{64\}/&${LF}/g"
```

or

```
LF=$'\\\x0A'
cat id_rsa.line | sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&${LF}/" -e "s/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/${LF}&${LF}/" | fold -w 64
```

Non-GNU `sed` does not interpret "\n" in the replacement as a newline.
As a workaround, you can assign a variable to a newline and embed it in the replacement.
Note that I've kept the UUC for readability :P.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [tshiono's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57882507/6242014) answer. Wrote a shell script to achieve the same:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Convert single-line certificate to multi-line certificate
echo "$1" > secret
LF=$'\\\x0A'; cat secret | sed -e "s/-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/&${LF}/" -e "s/-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----/${LF}&${LF}/" | sed -e "s/[^[:blank:]]\{64\}/&${LF}/g" > secret-temp
x=`echo "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"; cat secret-temp; echo "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"`
echo "$x" > secret.pem

echo "\n\n## Private Key ##\n\n"
cat secret.pem
```